# I seem to be losing the end of a string after exiting a for loop in c

Tags: c, pointers

I seem to be losing the end of my string after the exit of the for loop in the function below. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdint.h> 

char  *get_out_file_name(int in_file_num);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* file_name = get_out_file_name(37);
    printf("name_final = %s \n", file_name);
    free (file_name);
}
char *get_out_file_name(int in_file_num) 
 { 
     const int max_name_length = 3; 
     const int file_type_length = 4; 
     const char *type_suffix; 
     type_suffix = ".jpg"; 
     int num_remainder = in_file_num; 
     char * name_final = malloc(sizeof(char) * (max_name_length + file_type_length + 1));
    for (int i = max_name_length - 1; i >= 0 ; i --) 
     { 
         printf("i = %d\n",i); 
        name_final[i] = num_remainder % 10; 
        sprintf (&name_final[i], "%d", name_final[i]);
         printf("name_final[i] = %c \n", name_final[i]);
         num_remainder /= 10; 
     } 
    printf("pre concat[1] = %c \n",name_final[1]);
     strcat(name_final, type_suffix); 
   //  printf("name_final %s \n", name_final); 
     return name_final; 
}
```

The only place the data is retained is in name_final[0], array index 1 and 2 hold no data after the exit of the for loop.
I'm thinking it's possibly sprintf creates it's own local copy in the for loop or that I'm missing a reference/dereference somewhere. I was hoping someone could clarify.
The output is in the screenshot below. Apologies for the quality of the output screen grab. I'm having to use my phone to post.

[image: Output Screenshot]

Comment: sprintf will null terminate with each call, so you keep discarding all characters previously rewritten. If you just intend to do an integer to text conversion, there's multiple examples on this site of how to do that in better ways than using sprintf.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I understand now what's happening. Thanks for taking the time to reply

Answer (score 0):

I've just had chance to work out this function properly and wanted to give an explanation in case anyone stumbles across this in the future.

When I wrote that code I didn't understand how to convert a char by adding 0. I understand now that we don't actually add the value 0. We add the value 48 as this is the ASCII number/index for 0. All this is due to chars being saved as integers by c.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).